# How do I use np.newaxis?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting, numpy-ndarray

What is [`numpy.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) and when should I use it?

Using it on a 1-D array `x` produces:

```py
>>> x
array([0, 1, 2, 3])

>>> x[np.newaxis, :]
array([[0, 1, 2, 3]])

>>> x[:, np.newaxis]
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Comment: `except that it changes a row vector to a column vector?`  The first example is not a row vector.  That's a matlab concept.  In python it's just a 1-dimensional vector with no row or column concept.  Row or column vectors are 2-dimensonal, like the second example

Comment: That term does not come from matlab, it is a mathematical concept and a perfectly valid way to describe the arrays in his example. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198729/row-vector-vs-column-vector

Answer (score 682):

Simply put, [`numpy.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) is used to ***increase the dimension*** of the existing array by *one more dimension*, when used *once*. Thus,

- **1D** array will become **2D** array
- **2D** array will become **3D** array
- **3D** array will become **4D** array
- **4D** array will become **5D** array

and so on..

Here is a visual illustration which depicts *promotion* of 1D array to 2D arrays.

[image: newaxis canva visualization]

---

**Scenario-1**: [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) might come in handy when you want to *explicitly* convert a 1D array to either a *row vector* or a *column vector*, as depicted in the above picture.

**Example:**

```
# 1D array
In [7]: arr = np.arange(4)
In [8]: arr.shape
Out[8]: (4,)

# make it as row vector by inserting an axis along first dimension
In [9]: row_vec = arr[np.newaxis, :]     # arr[None, :]
In [10]: row_vec.shape
Out[10]: (1, 4)

# make it as column vector by inserting an axis along second dimension
In [11]: col_vec = arr[:, np.newaxis]     # arr[:, None]
In [12]: col_vec.shape
Out[12]: (4, 1)
```

---

**Scenario-2**: When we want to make use of [**numpy broadcasting**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) as part of some operation, for instance while doing *addition* of some arrays.

**Example:**

Let's say you want to add the following two arrays:

```
 x1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
 x2 = np.array([5, 4, 3])
```

If you try to add these just like that, NumPy will raise the following `ValueError` :

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (3,)
```

In this situation, you can use [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) to increase the dimension of one of the arrays so that NumPy can [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```
In [2]: x1_new = x1[:, np.newaxis]    # x1[:, None]
# now, the shape of x1_new is (5, 1)
# array([[1],
#        [2],
#        [3],
#        [4],
#        [5]])
```

Now, add:

```
In [3]: x1_new + x2
Out[3]:
array([[ 6,  5,  4],
       [ 7,  6,  5],
       [ 8,  7,  6],
       [ 9,  8,  7],
       [10,  9,  8]])
```

---

Alternatively, you can also add new axis to the array `x2`:

```
In [6]: x2_new = x2[:, np.newaxis]    # x2[:, None]
In [7]: x2_new     # shape is (3, 1)
Out[7]: 
array([[5],
       [4],
       [3]])
```

Now, add:

```
In [8]: x1 + x2_new
Out[8]: 
array([[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8]])
```

**Note**: Observe that we get the same result in both cases (but one being the transpose of the other).

---

**Scenario-3**: This is similar to scenario-1. But, you can use [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) more than once to *promote* the array to higher dimensions. Such an operation is sometimes needed for higher order arrays (*i.e. Tensors*).

**Example:**

```
In [124]: arr = np.arange(5*5).reshape(5,5)

In [125]: arr.shape
Out[125]: (5, 5)

# promoting 2D array to a 5D array
In [126]: arr_5D = arr[np.newaxis, ..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis]    # arr[None, ..., None, None]

In [127]: arr_5D.shape
Out[127]: (1, 5, 5, 1, 1)
```

As an alternative, you can use [`numpy.expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) that has an intuitive `axis` kwarg.

```
# adding new axes at 1st, 4th, and last dimension of the resulting array
In [131]: newaxes = (0, 3, -1)
In [132]: arr_5D = np.expand_dims(arr, axis=newaxes)
In [133]: arr_5D.shape
Out[133]: (1, 5, 5, 1, 1)
```

---

**More background on [np.newaxis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) vs [np.reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)**

[`newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) is also called as a pseudo-index that allows the temporary addition of an axis into a multiarray.

[`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) uses the slicing operator to recreate the array while [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) reshapes the array to the desired layout (assuming that the dimensions match; And this is ***must*** for a [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to happen).

**Example**

```
In [13]: A = np.ones((3,4,5,6))
In [14]: B = np.ones((4,6))
In [15]: (A + B[:, np.newaxis, :]).shape     # B[:, None, :]
Out[15]: (3, 4, 5, 6)
```

In the above example, we inserted a temporary axis between the first and second axes of `B` (to use broadcasting). A missing axis is filled-in here using [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) to make the [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) operation work.

---

***General Tip***: You can also use `None` in place of [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis); These are in fact the [same objects](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).

```
In [13]: np.newaxis is None
Out[13]: True
```

P.S. Also see this great answer: [newaxis vs reshape to add dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28385957)

Comment: What type of operation is x1_new + x2? It is weird to me because I thought that two matrices can only be added if they have the same dimensions (or if one of them is actually just a scalar).

Comment: @Stephen As I also noted in the answer, it's because of NumPy Broadcasting.

Comment: Either @kmario23 == Ian Dzindo, or Ian Dzindo01 plagiarized this answer in this 2018 Medium post: https://medium.com/@ian.dzindo01/what-is-numpy-newaxis-and-when-to-use-it-8cb61c7ed6ae.

Comment: @ChirazBenAbdelkader I'm not the one who wrote that medium post. Yes, it's ditto copying but there was an attribution at the end of the article, although I'd prefer it to be at the beginning.

Comment: @kmario23  Indeed the attribution is hidden in the very last sentence of the article, no wonder I did not see it. I consider it borderline plagiarism even with this attribution. In my book, word for word copying is only acceptable if it's the same author posting on different platforms. I expected better from Medium.

Comment: "Wait, it's all `None`? -Always has been."

Answer (score 55):

### What is `np.newaxis`?

The `np.newaxis` is just an alias for the Python constant `None`, which means that wherever you use `np.newaxis` you could also use `None`:

```
>>> np.newaxis is None
True
```

It's just more *descriptive* if you read code that uses `np.newaxis` instead of `None`.

### How to use `np.newaxis`?

The `np.newaxis` is generally used with slicing. It indicates that you want to add an additional dimension to the array. The position of the `np.newaxis` represents where I want to add dimensions.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a.shape
(10,)
```

In the first example I use all elements from the first dimension and add a second dimension:

```
>>> a[:, np.newaxis]
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
>>> a[:, np.newaxis].shape
(10, 1)
```

The second example adds a dimension as first dimension and then uses all elements from the first dimension of the original array as elements in the second dimension of the result array:

```
>>> a[np.newaxis, :]  # The output has 2 [] pairs!
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
>>> a[np.newaxis, :].shape
(1, 10)
```

Similarly you can use multiple `np.newaxis` to add multiple dimensions:

```
>>> a[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]  # note the 3 [] pairs in the output
array([[[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5],
        [6],
        [7],
        [8],
        [9]]])
>>> a[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis].shape
(1, 10, 1)
```

### Are there alternatives to `np.newaxis`?

There is another very similar functionality in NumPy: [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html#numpy.expand_dims), which can also be used to insert one dimension:

```
>>> np.expand_dims(a, 1)  # like a[:, np.newaxis]
>>> np.expand_dims(a, 0)  # like a[np.newaxis, :]
```

But given that it just inserts `1`s in the `shape` you could also `reshape` the array to add these dimensions:

```
>>> a.reshape(a.shape + (1,))  # like a[:, np.newaxis]
>>> a.reshape((1,) + a.shape)  # like a[np.newaxis, :]
```

Most of the times `np.newaxis` is the easiest way to add dimensions, but it's good to know the alternatives.

### When to use `np.newaxis`?

In several contexts is adding dimensions useful:

- If the data should have a specified number of dimensions. For example if you want to use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` to display a 1D array.
- If you want NumPy to broadcast arrays. By adding a dimension you could for example get the difference between all elements of one array: `a - a[:, np.newaxis]`. This works because NumPy operations broadcast starting with the last dimension <sup>1</sup>.
- To add a necessary dimension so that NumPy *can* broadcast arrays. This works because each length-1 dimension is simply broadcast to the length of the corresponding<sup>1</sup> dimension of the other array.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you want to read more about the broadcasting rules the [NumPy documentation on that subject](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) is very good. It also includes an example with `np.newaxis`:

> ```
> >>> a = np.array([0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0])
> >>> b = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
> >>> a[:, np.newaxis] + b
> array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
>        [ 11.,  12.,  13.],
>        [ 21.,  22.,  23.],
>        [ 31.,  32.,  33.]])
> ```

Comment: I don't see the difference between the 2nd and 3rd use cases; they're both about allowing NumPy to broadcast an array as part of some operation. If not, then it would help to add an example for the 3rd use case in order to clarify the point.

Comment: @ChirazBenAbdelkader Yeah, the distinction isn't really that distinct. I'm not sure if I should remove the third point or merge it into the second one.

Answer (score 12):

You started with a one-dimensional list of numbers.  Once you used `numpy.newaxis`, you turned it into a two-dimensional matrix, consisting of four rows of one column each.

You could then use that matrix for matrix multiplication, or involve it in the construction of a larger 4 x n matrix.

Answer (score 6):

`newaxis` object in the selection tuple serves to **expand the dimensions** of the resulting selection by **one unit-length** dimension.

It is not just conversion of row matrix to column matrix.

Consider the example below:

```
In [1]:x1 = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
       print(x1)
Out[1]: array([[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [7, 8, 9]])
```

Now lets add new dimension to our data,

```
In [2]:x1_new = x1[:,np.newaxis]
       print(x1_new)
Out[2]:array([[[1, 2, 3]],

              [[4, 5, 6]],

              [[7, 8, 9]]])
```

You can see that `newaxis` added the extra dimension here, x1 had dimension (3,3) and X1_new has dimension (3,1,3).

How our new dimension enables us to different operations:

```
In [3]:x2 = np.arange(11,20).reshape(3,3)
       print(x2)
Out[3]:array([[11, 12, 13],
              [14, 15, 16],
              [17, 18, 19]])
```

Adding x1_new and x2, we get:

```
In [4]:x1_new+x2
Out[4]:array([[[12, 14, 16],
               [15, 17, 19],
               [18, 20, 22]],

              [[15, 17, 19],
               [18, 20, 22],
               [21, 23, 25]],

              [[18, 20, 22],
               [21, 23, 25],
               [24, 26, 28]]])
```

Thus, `newaxis` is not just conversion of row to column matrix. It increases the dimension of matrix, thus enabling us to do more operations on it.

Comment: It's not just matrix, it works with any `ndarray` in NumPy terminology.

Comment: .... and even PyTorch tensors

Answer (score 0):

It expands dims on where it is.

For example: `arr[newaxis]` is equal to `expand_dims(arr, 0)`。

`arr[:, newaxis]` is equal to `expand_dims(arr, 1)`

`arr[:, :, newaxis]` is equal to `expand_dims(arr, 2)`