# Is this type of indexing a transposition of Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, transpose, numpy-slicing

I'm following certain tutorials for science proposals in Python and I've encounter this way of using indexing:

```
import numpy as np
l=np.array([8,5,2,3])
print(l[:,None])
```

What this print returns is:

```
[[8]
 [5]
 [2]
 [3]]
```

It is obvious what this code does and I find it very useful for my proposal but It would never have occurred to me using it because I don't understand what this slicing syntax is saying.

Anyone can explain me how this type of slicing works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ':' is a place holder for [all of them](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: I understand this, but what I don't really understand is passing the second part ',None', because the original array has not two dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

`:` is placeholder for all elements and `None` is `np.newaxis`, if you are trying to slice extra shape then `None` will tell numpy make new dimension.

So the proper way to write your example and avoid confusion will be:

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([8, 5, 2, 3])
print(l[:, np.newaxis])
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is upscaling of the array dimension from 1D to 2D, a column vector to be precise. The most common way to do this is using [`None or np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) :

```
In [317]: l = np.array([8,5,2,3])

In [318]: l[:, np.newaxis]
Out[318]: 
array([[8],
       [5],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [319]: l.shape
Out[319]: (4,)

In [320]: l[:, np.newaxis].shape
Out[320]: (4, 1)
```

But, you can also convert it into a row vector using:

```
In [321]: l[np.newaxis, :]
Out[321]: array([[8, 5, 2, 3]])

In [322]: (l[np.newaxis, :]).shape
Out[322]: (1, 4)
```

So, `:` means *select all the elements* from the array along a particular axis during the slicing operation.

See [how np.newaxis work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41267079/2956066) for more information.