# How can i get sub array depending on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

For example, i have an complex array of shape (3,3,3) and i want to find angle of the element when magnitude of the array along axis 2 is maximum.
That is,

```
a = np.random.random((3, 3, 3)) + 1j * np.random.random((3, 3, 3))

amp3d = np.abs(a)
amp2d = np.max(amp3d, axis=2)

angle2d =  np.zeros_like(amp2d)

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        for k in range(a.shape[2]):
            if amp3d[i, j, k] == amp2d[i,j]:
                angle2d[i, j] = np.angle(a[i, j, k])
```

Of course i can loop, but i guess there is exist a pretty pythonic way to accomplish this task

In Matlab it would be look similar to `np.angle(a[np.argmax(a, axis=2)])`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [mask/boolean array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) for the relevant values by expanding the dimension of `amp2d` to match the dimension of `amp3d`, and multiply that with `a` and select the maximum value for `axis=2`.

```
a = np.random.random((3, 3, 3)) + 1j * np.random.random((3, 3, 3))

amp3d = np.abs(a)
amp2d = np.max(amp3d, axis=2)

mask = amp3d == amp2d[...,np.newaxis]
angle2d = np.angle((a*mask).max(axis=2))
```

Check the [numpy documentation on indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for reference what `np.newaxis` does, or check [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241056/how-does-numpy-newaxis-work-and-when-to-use-it).