# Concatenating two NumPy arrays gives "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, valueerror

header
output:

```
array(['Subject_ID', 'tube_label', 'sample_#', 'Relabel', 
      'sample_ID','cortisol_value', 'Group'], dtype='<U14')
```

body
output:

```
array([['STM002', '170714_STM002_1', 1, 1, 1, 1.98, 'HC'],
       ['STM002', '170714_STM002_2', 2, 2, 2, 2.44, 'HC'],], dtype=object)

testing = np.concatenate((header, body), axis=0)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-302-efb002602b4b> in <module>()
      1 # Merge names and the rest of the data in np array
      2 
----> 3 testing = np.concatenate((header, body), axis=0)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Might someone be able to troubleshoot this?
I have tried different commands to merge the two (including stack) and am getting the same error. The dimensions (columns) do seem to be the same though.

Comment: How do you want to combine these? They have completely different shapes.  Numpy doesn't deal well with jagged arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to align array dimensions first. You are currently trying to combine 1-dimensional and 2-dimensional arrays. After alignment, you can use [`numpy.vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).

Note `np.array([A]).shape` returns `(1, 7)`, while `B.shape` returns `(2, 7)`. A more efficient alternative would be to use `A[None, :]`.

Also note your array will become of dtype `object`, as this will accept arbitrary / mixed types.

```
A = np.array(['Subject_ID', 'tube_label', 'sample_#', 'Relabel', 
              'sample_ID','cortisol_value', 'Group'], dtype='<U14')

B = np.array([['STM002', '170714_STM002_1', 1, 1, 1, 1.98, 'HC'],
              ['STM002', '170714_STM002_2', 2, 2, 2, 2.44, 'HC'],], dtype=object)

res = np.vstack((np.array([A]), B))

print(res)

array([['Subject_ID', 'tube_label', 'sample_#', 'Relabel', 'sample_ID',
        'cortisol_value', 'Group'],
       ['STM002', '170714_STM002_1', 1, 1, 1, 1.98, 'HC'],
       ['STM002', '170714_STM002_2', 2, 2, 2, 2.44, 'HC']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're right in trying to use [`numpy.concatenate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) but you've to *promote* the first array to 2D before concatenating. Here's a simple example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: arr1 = np.array(['Subject_ID', 'tube_label', 'sample_#', 'Relabel', 
   ...:       'sample_ID','cortisol_value', 'Group'], dtype='<U14')
   ...:       

In [3]: arr2 = np.array([['STM002', '170714_STM002_1', 1, 1, 1, 1.98, 'HC'],
   ...:        ['STM002', '170714_STM002_2', 2, 2, 2, 2.44, 'HC'],], dtype=object)
   ...:        

In [4]: arr1.shape
Out[4]: (7,)

In [5]: arr2.shape
Out[5]: (2, 7)

In [8]: concatenated = np.concatenate((arr1[None, :], arr2), axis=0)

In [9]: concatenated.shape
Out[9]: (3, 7)
```

And the resultant concatenated array would look like:

```
In [10]: concatenated
Out[10]: 
array([['Subject_ID', 'tube_label', 'sample_#', 'Relabel', 'sample_ID',
        'cortisol_value', 'Group'],
       ['STM002', '170714_STM002_1', 1, 1, 1, 1.98, 'HC'],
       ['STM002', '170714_STM002_2', 2, 2, 2, 2.44, 'HC']], dtype=object)
```

---

#### Explanation:

The reason you were getting the `ValueError` is because one of the arrays is 1D while the other is 2D. But, `numpy.concatenate` expects the arrays to be of same dimension in this case. That's why we *promoted* the array dimension of `arr1` using `None`. But, you can also use [`numpy.newaxis`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241056/how-does-numpy-newaxis-work-and-when-to-use-it) in place of `None`

Answer (score 0):

Look at numpy.vstack and hstack, as well as the axis argument in np.append. Here it looks like you want vstack (i.e. the output array will have 3 columns, each with the same number of rows). You can also look into numpy.reshape, to change the shape of the input arrays so you can concatenate them.

Comment: Thank you for the info!
I tried vstack, and am getting a similar error. However, it looks like both have the same number of colums (7). Does it look like there is an issue in there? thank you so much,

Comment: What are the shapes of each array? You can check with (e.g. for a numpy array `bar`) `bar.shape`. If you want to stack, every dimension should be the same except the one in which you're stacking.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the bar.shape- very helpful in reshaping and checking the result. I got it to work.