# Is there a fast way to multiply one axis of a 4D array by elements in a vector of the same length as that axis?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two lists of shape (130, 64, 2048), call it (s, f, b), and one vector of length 64, call this v. I need to append these two lists together to make a list of shape (130, 2, 64, 2048) and multiply all 2048 values in f[i] with the i th value of v.

The output array also needs to have shape (130, 2, 64, 2048)

Obviously these two steps can be done interchangeably. I want to know the most Pythonic way of doing something like this.

My main issue is that my code takes forever in turning the list into a numpy array which is necessary for some of my calculations. I have:

```py
new_prof = np.asarray( new_prof )
```

but this seems to take two long for the size and shape of my list. Any thoughts as to how I could initialise this better?

The problem outlined above is shown by my attempt:

```py
    # Converted data should have shape (130, 2, 64, 2048)
    converted_data = IQUV_to_AABB( data, basis = "cartesian" )

    new_converted = np.array((130, 2, 64, 2048))

    # I think s.shape is (2, 64, 2048) and cal_fa has length 64
    for i, s in enumerate( converted_data ):
        aa = np.dot( s[0], cal_fa )
        bb = np.dot( s[1], cal_fb )
        new_converted[i].append( (aa, bb) )
```

However, this code doesn't work and I think it's got something to do with the dot product. Maybe??

I would also love to know why the process of changing my list to a numpy array is taking so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to start small and look at the results in the console:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(36)
print(x)

y = np.reshape(x, (3, 4, 3))
print(y)

# this is a vector of the same size as dimension 1
a = np.arange(4)
print(a)

# expand and let numpy's broadcasting do the rest
# https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html
# https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc
b = a[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]
print(b)

c = y * b
print(c)
```

You can read about `np.newaxis` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis), [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241056/how-does-numpy-newaxis-work-and-when-to-use-it).

Using `numpy.append` is rather slow as it has to preallocate memory and copy the whole array each time. A numpy array is a continuous block of memory.

You might have to use it if you run out of computer memory. But in this case try to iterate over *appropriate* chunks, as big as your computer can still handle them. Re-aranging the dimension is sometimes a way to speed up calculations.