# Different shape arrays operations

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

A bit of background:
I want to calculate the array factor of a MxN antenna array, which is given by the following equation:

[image: eq1]
Where w_i are the complex weight of the i-th element, (x_i,y_i,z_i) is the position of the i-th element, k is the wave number, theta and phi are the elevation and azimuth respectively, and i ranges from 0 to MxN-1.

In the code I have:

-theta and phi are np.mgrid with shape (200,200) each,

-w_i, and (x,y,z)_i are np.array with shape (NxM,) each

so AF is a np.array with shape (200,200) (sum over i).There is no problem so far, and I can get AF easily doing:

```py
af = zeros([theta.shape[0],phi.shape[0]])
for i in range(self.size[0]*self.size[1]):
            af = af + ( w[i]*e**(-1j*(k * x_pos[i]*sin(theta)*cos(phi) + k * y_pos[i]* sin(theta)*sin(phi)+ k * z_pos[i] * cos(theta))) )
```

Now, each w_i depends on frequency, so AF too, and now I have w_i with shape (NxM,1000) (I have 1000 samples of each w_i in frequency). I tried to use the above code changing

```py
af = zeros([1000,theta.shape[0],phi.shape[0]])
```

but I get 'operands could not be broadcast together'. I can solve this by using a for loop through the 1000 values, but it is slow and is a bit ugly. So, what is the correct way to do the summation, or the correct way to properly define w_i and AF ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**edit**
The code with the new dimension I'm trying to add is the next:

```py
from numpy import *

class AntennaArray:
    def __init__(self,f,asize=None,tipo=None,dx=None,dy=None):
        self.Lambda = 299792458 / f
        self.k = 2*pi/self.Lambda
        self.size = asize
        self.type = tipo
        self._AF_DATA_SIZE = 200
        self.theta,self.phi =  mgrid[0 : pi : self._AF_DATA_SIZE*1j,0 : 2*pi : self._AF_DATA_SIZE*1j]

        self.element_pos = None
        self.element_amp = None
        self.element_pha = None

        if dx == None:
            self.dx = self.Lambda/2
        else:
            self.dx = dx

        if dy == None:
            self.dy = self.Lambda/2
        else:
            self.dy = dy


        self.generate_array()


    def generate_array(self):


        M = self.size[0]
        N = self.size[1]
        dx = self.dx
        dy = self.dy

        x_pos = arange(0,dx*N,dx)
        y_pos = arange(0,dy*M,dy)
        z_pos = 0

        ele = zeros([N*M,3])

        for i in range(M):
            ele[i*N:(i+1)*N,0] = x_pos[:]


        for i in range(M):
            ele[i*N:(i+1)*N,1] = y_pos[i]


        self.element_pos = ele


        #self.array_factor = self.calculate_array_factor()

    def calculate_array_factor(self):

        theta,phi = self.theta,self.phi

        k = self.k

        x_pos = self.element_pos[:,0]
        y_pos = self.element_pos[:,1]
        z_pos = self.element_pos[:,2]

        w = self.element_amp*exp(1j*self.element_pha)



        if len(self.element_pha.shape) > 1:
            #I have f_size samples of w_i(f)
            f_size = self.element_pha.shape[1]
            af = zeros([f_size,theta.shape[0],phi.shape[0]])
        else:
            #I only have w_i
            af = zeros([theta.shape[0],phi.shape[0]])


        for i in range(self.size[0]*self.size[1]):
        **strong text**#This for loop does the summation over i
            af = af + ( w[i]*e**(-1j*(k * x_pos[i]*sin(theta)*cos(phi) + k * y_pos[i]* sin(theta)*sin(phi)+ k * z_pos[i] * cos(theta))) )
        return af
```

I tried  to test it with the next main

```py
from numpy import *
f_points = 10

M = 2
N = 2

a = AntennaArray(5.8e9,[M,N])

a.element_amp = ones([M*N,f_points])
a.element_pha = zeros([M*N,f_points])

af = a.calculate_array_factor()
```

But I get

ValueError: 'operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (200,200) '

Note that if I set

```py
a.element_amp = ones([M*N])
a.element_pha = zeros([M*N])
```

This works well.

Thanks.

Comment: Why the `for` loop to implement the equation? You said you have `numpy` arrays, you don't need the for loop. And on what? Seems you have flattened everything. This is totally not needed. What is `self`? Is that inside a method in a class? If you give us more background on your code, is better.

Comment: I have updated the post with the complete code. The `for` is for the summation only. The others arrays are only 1D because I am summing over them, and the final shape is the (200,200) of the numpy.mgrid. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the code, and I think this `for` loop:

```
af = zeros([theta.shape[0],phi.shape[0]])
for i in range(self.size[0]*self.size[1]):
            af = af + ( w[i]*e**(-1j*(k * x_pos[i]*sin(theta)*cos(phi) + k * y_pos[i]* sin(theta)*sin(phi)+ k * z_pos[i] * cos(theta))) )
```

is wrong in many ways. You are mixing dimensions, you cannot loop that way.
And by the way, to make full use of `numpy` efficiency, **never** loop over the arrays. It slows down the execution significantly.

I tried to rework that part.

First, I advice you to not use `from numpy import *`, it's bad practice (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)). Use `import numpy as np`. I reintroduced the `np` abbreviation, so you can understand what comes from `numpy`.

#### Frequency independent case

This first snippet assumes that `w` is a 1D array of length 4: I am neglecting the frequency dependency of `w`, to show you how you can get what you already obtained without the `for` loop and using instead the power of `numpy`.

```
af_points = w[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]*np.e**(-1j*
           (k * x_pos[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi) + 
            k * y_pos[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi) + 
            k * z_pos[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]*np.cos(theta)
           ))
af = np.sum(af_points, axis=0)
```

I am using [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to obtain a 3D array named `af_points`, whose shape is `(4, 200, 200)`. To do it, I use `np.newaxis` to extend the number of axis of an array in order to use broadcasting correctly. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241056/how-does-numpy-newaxis-work-and-when-to-use-it) on `np.newaxis`.
So, `w[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]` is an array of shape (4, 1, 1). Similarly for `x_pos[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]`, `y_pos[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]` and `z_pos[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]`. Since the angles have shape (200, 200), broadcasting can be done, and `af_points` has shape (4, 200, 200).
Finally the sum is done by `np.sum`, summing over the first axis to obtain a (200, 200) array.

#### Frequency dependent case

Now `w` has shape (4, 10), where 10 are the frequency points. The idea is the same, just consider that the frequency is an additional dimension in your numpy arrays: now `af_points` will be an array of shape (4, 10, 200, 200) where 10 are the `f_points` you have defined.

To keep it understandable, I've split the calculation:

```
#exp_point is only the exponent, frequency independent. Will be a (4, 200, 200) array.
exp_points = np.e**(-1j*
            (k * x_pos[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi) + 
             k * y_pos[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi) +
             k * z_pos[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]*np.cos(theta)
            ))
af_points = w[:,:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis] * exp_points[:,np.newaxis,:,:]
af = np.sum(af_points, axis=0)
```

And now `af` has shape (10, 200, 200).

Comment: Now I understand what you mean with flattened. I did not understand the concept of broadcasting until your explanation. Thanks a lot.