# Array conforming shape of a given variable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, netcdf, netcdf4, ncl

I need to do some calculations with a NetCDF file. 
So I have two variables with following dimensions and sizes:

```
A [time | 1] x [lev | 12] x [lat | 84] x [lon | 228]
B [lev | 12]
```

What I need is to produce a new array, `C`, that is shaped as `(1,12,84,228)` where `B` contents are propagated to all dimensions of `A`.

Usually, this is easily done in NCL with the conform function. I am not sure what is the equivalent of this in Python.

Thank you.

Comment: You will need Numpy's broadcasting options: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html . This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41267079/3581217 is a pretty good SO answer which shows the different options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [numpy.broadcast_to](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) function can do something like this, although in this case it does require `B` to have a couple of extra trailing size 1 dimension added to it to satisfy the [numpy broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
>>> import numpy
>>> B = numpy.arange(12).reshape(12, 1, 1)
>>> B
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
>>> B = B.reshape(12, 1, 1)
>>> B.shape
(12, 1, 1)
>>> C = numpy.broadcast_to(b, (1, 12, 84, 228))
>>> C.shape
(1, 12, 84, 228)
>>> C[0, :, 0, 0]
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
>>> C[-1, :, -1, -1]
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```