# How can I speed the training up for a model with a custom loss function in Keras?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow, keras

I defined a custom loss function for Deep Metric Learning in Keras, and I get abysmal performance in Colab with a GPU accelerator, notwithstanding the simplicity of the problem. What can I do to speed the training up?

Sample code: the code is written to be run in Colab/Jupyter, but I guess it could be run as a script too (I didn't try, but I don't see any obvious reason why it shouldn't work).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = (X_train / 255.0).astype('float32')
X_test = (X_test / 255.0).astype('float32')

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

embedding_size = 3
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape = input_shape))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(embedding_size))

model.summary()

margin = 0.2
def contrastive_loss(y_true, embeddings):
  loss = 0.0

  b = embeddings.shape[0]
  
  for i in range(0,b):
    yi = y_true[i]
    xi = embeddings[i]

    for j in range(i+1,b):
      yj = y_true[j]
      xj = embeddings[j]

      yij = tf.minimum(1.0, tf.abs(tf.cast(yi-yj, dtype = tf.float32)))
      distance = tf.norm(xi-xj)
      loss = loss + (1-yij)*distance**2 + yij*tf.maximum(0.0, margin-distance)**2
    
  loss = 0.5 * loss 
  return loss

model.compile(keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), loss=contrastive_loss)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, shuffle=True)

print(X_test.shape)
emb = model.predict(X_test)
print(emb.shape, "emb")
print(y_test.shape, "y_test")
plt.scatter(emb[:,0], emb[:,1], c=y_test, cmap='tab10')
```

The training is very slow on Colab with GPU accelerator. Any hints on how I could speed it up? Right now I get > 200 ms/step, i.e., ≈ 380 s per epoch.

**EDIT**: initially I wrote a stripped-down version of the actual code, but, according to some comments, the way to speed the code up may depend on what I actually compute inside the loss function, so I now put the actual code. Sorry if that makes the code go slower...

**EDIT2**: I tried to implement the solution in Jeff's answer but I'm getting an error whose cause I don't understand. Here's the new code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = (X_train / 255.0).astype('float32')
X_test = (X_test / 255.0).astype('float32')

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

embedding_size = 3
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape = input_shape))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(embedding_size))

model.summary() 

margin = 0.2
def contrastive_loss(y_true, embeddings):

  # it's easier to work with a flattened array
  flat_y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, (-1)) 

  # matrix of absolute differences, clipped to 1 (if yi!=yj then yij =1)
  yijs = abs(np.subtract.outer(flat_y_true, flat_y_true)).clip(max=1) 

  # we only need the upper triangular part of the matrix
  yijs = yijs[np.triu_indices_from(yijs)] 

  # first compute row differences of the embeddings matrix, the compute norms for
  # each row with axis=2
  distances = np.linalg.norm(embeddings[:,None] - embeddings[None], axis=2)

  # we only need the upper triangular part, again
  distances = distances[np.triu_indices_from(distances)]

  loss = ((1-yijs)*(distances**2) + (yijs*((margin-distances).clip(min=0)**2))).sum()*0.5

  return loss

model.compile(keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), loss=contrastive_loss)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, shuffle=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-1ae713ccf38c> in <module>()
      4 
      5 # When setting batch size, remember we are *quadratically* expanding it in our loss.
----> 6 history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, shuffle=True)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    <ipython-input-4-6c3b8535eb43>:5 contrastive_loss  *
        flat_y_true = tf.reshape(y_true, (-1))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py:195 reshape
        result = gen_array_ops.reshape(tensor, shape, name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py:8234 reshape
        "Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:744 _apply_op_helper
        attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:593 _create_op_internal
        compute_device)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:3485 _create_op_internal
        op_def=op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1975 __init__
        control_input_ops, op_def)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1815 _create_c_op
        raise ValueError(str(e))

    ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for '{{node contrastive_loss/Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_UINT8, Tshape=DT_INT32](ExpandDims, contrastive_loss/Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [32,1], [].
```

Comment: Your loss function includes multiple python `for` loops iterating through your tensors, which is my guess at your source of inefficiency. Look for functions built-in to `tensorflow` that are optimized for such operations.

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the suggestion. I did have a look, but what I found so far are suggestions to write a _train_ loop, i.e., [reimplement the `fit` method from scratch](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch). I don't want to do that - the standard `fit` is ok for my purposes, so I don't need tools such as `tf.GradientTape()` or similar. I would need something like a Tensorflow `for` loop....

Comment: @jeff thanks for the support - the actual code is a bit more complicated. I'll include the real loss function - I wanted to keep things simple, but since the answer apparently depends on what I compute exactly, I'll write the real deal. I'll be glad to answer any other questions of yours, and by all means, let's postpone this to when you're back for work.

Comment: @Jeff clarification given  thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/contrastive_loss) isn't what you're looking for, we'll give it a go at implementing it ourselves.

Since the python for loops in your loss function are likely the problem we'll focus our efforts there.

EDIT: I guess I need to get some more sleep because I could've sworn I got `numpy` functions to work in custom `tensorflow` loss functions before. Switched all operations to `tensorflow` operations as this is actually not the case.

---

Edited Full function:

```
def contrastive_loss(y_true, embeddings):
    
    yijs = tf.cast(tf.reshape((y_true[:,None]!=y_true),(y_true.get_shape()[0],y_true.get_shape()[0])),tf.dtypes.float32)
    distances = tf.norm(tf.cast(embeddings[:,None]-embeddings,tf.dtypes.float32),axis=2)
    dist_len = distances.get_shape()[0]
    return tf.math.reduce_sum((1-yijs)*distances**2 + yijs*(tf.maximum(0.2-distances,tf.zeros((dist_len,dist_len)))**2))*0.25
```

---

Edited Line-by-Line walkthrough:

```
def contrastive_loss(y_true, embeddings):
    y_true_len = y_true.get_shape()[0] #shape (None,1)
    yijs = tf.cast(
        tf.reshape(
            (
                #Max clipping abs diff of every value and all other values 
                #to 1 is essentially checking whether 
                #the other values are equal to itself or not
                #this would be a much faster method of doing so
                y_true[:,None]!=y_true
            ),
            #resize to square matrix of shape (batch_size,batch_size)
            (y_true_len,y_true_len) 
        ),
        tf.dtypes.float32 
    )
    
    distances = tf.norm(
        tf.cast(
            #find difference between each row and all other rows
            embeddings[:,None]-embeddings,
            tf.dtypes.float32
        ),
        #normalize every row to find 
        #magnitude of every row vector
        axis=2 
    )
    
    #get len to setup equivalent square matrix tensor of 0's later
    dist_len = distances.get_shape()[0] 
    #Sums all values in tensor
    loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(
        (1-yijs)*(distances**2) 
        + yijs*(
            #clip all values to be above 0
            tf.maximum(
                0.2-distances,
                #declare tensor of same dimension as 0.2-distances
                #for element wise comparison so tf.maximum can do its thing
                tf.zeros((dist_len,dist_len))
            )**2
        )
    )*0.25 #since we didn't drop lower triangle, need to multiply by 0.25 instead of 0.5
    
    return loss
```

Comment: Give it a gander and see if that's what you want. I generated some small toy examples on my end to test it out and it seems like it yields the same answer as your previous loss function. This should speed up the process a lot during training, but if it's still too slow there might be more opportunities to optimize the functions further like skipping `triu` or coding the `np.linalg.norm` ourselves

Comment: a single +1 doesn'r really do justice to your work, expect a bounty coming your way soon and btw, yes, `tfa.losses.contrastive_loss` is _exactly_ what I was trying to replicate. I didn't want to use that, because my goal was not implementation _per se_, but learning how to code custom loss functions efficiently in Keras. As always, the best way to learn is to find a great teacher and you're one. If you don't mind me asking, are you one of the `tensorflow` or `keras` contributors?

Comment: I spoke too soon  I made some minor modifications for clarity, but the code isn't working...can you help? I'm adding the new code with the error message to my question. I can also ask a new question if you prefer.

Comment: @DeltaIV oof I've seen those before and they're a pain, I'll have a look again when I get back home. I'm also no where near good enough to be a contributor hence why we're seeing this error lol -.-

Comment: @DeltaIV Answer is updated, lmk if you still have problems

Comment: thanks! I'll test it tomorrow. Can you explain what's the meaning of the syntax `x[:,None]-x`? You use it in two places (`embeddings[:,None]-embeddings` and `y_true[:,None]!=y_true`), so it seems important for the solution. But I'm not sure what it does.

Comment: @DeltaIV `array[:,None]` is the same as `array[:,np.newaxis]` which simply inserts a dimension on the selected axis e.g `array.shape = (3,4)` then `array[:,None] = (3,1,4)`. We do this so that the broadcasted subtraction can occur against the correct axes, where every element of the second axis (which is the new extra dimension we wrapped along each row) is subtracted by the original 2D array, achieving our effect of differencing every row with all other rows. For more info see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241056/how-does-numpy-newaxis-work-and-when-to-use-it, scenario 2 of answer 1.