# Plot multiple graphs without using a for loop

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, graph, algebra

So, my question may not be exactly what is in the title.

I have a function

y = a*x + b

And I want to plot y whith different values of b.

I know that I can do the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 2
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
b = 0

for i in range(10):
    y = a*x + b
    b = b+1
    plt.plot(x,y)
```

And that returns exactly what I want.

But, there is someway that I can make this by using
`b = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])`? So, then my code could look something like:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 2
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

y = a*x + b
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use matrix operations to create a 2D matrix with the result of the operation `y = a*x + b`.

```
a = 2
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
b = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

y = a*x[:,None]+b
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

**EDIT:** I'm shwing the solution provided by [@Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) which is much simpler than mine.
original code was:

```
y = np.tile(a*x, (b.size,1)) + b[:,np.newaxis]
plt.plot(x, y.T)
```

Comment: also `y = a*x[:, None] + b` and `plt.plot(x,y)`

Comment: @QuangHoang of course, much simpler. Don't know why I went the other direction. Thanks for that

Comment: Cool! But, I dont think I understand what is happening here. Isnt that the same of `y = a*np.transpose(x) + b`?

Comment: No, you need to transform your vector to a 2D matrix. The transpose of a vector is the same vector. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241056/how-does-numpy-newaxis-work-and-when-to-use-it