# Attention weighted aggregation

Tags: pytorch, tensor, torch

Let the tensor shown below be the representation of two sentences (batch_size = 2) composed with 3 words (max_lenght = 3) and each word being represented by vectors of dimension equal to 5 (hidden_size = 5) obtained as output from a neural network:

```py
net_output
# tensor([[[0.7718, 0.3856, 0.2545, 0.7502, 0.5844],
#          [0.4400, 0.3753, 0.4840, 0.2483, 0.4751],
#          [0.4927, 0.7380, 0.1502, 0.5222, 0.0093]],

#         [[0.5859, 0.0010, 0.2261, 0.6318, 0.5636],
#          [0.0996, 0.2178, 0.9003, 0.4708, 0.7501],
#          [0.4244, 0.7947, 0.5711, 0.0720, 0.1106]]])
```

Also consider the following attention scores:

```py
att_scores
# tensor([[0.2425, 0.5279, 0.2295],
#         [0.2461, 0.4789, 0.2751]])
```

Which efficient approach allows obtaining the aggregation of vectors in `net_output` weighted by `att_scores` resulting in a vector of shape (2, 5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
weighted = (net_output * att_scores[..., None]).sum(axis = 1)
```

Uses broadcasting to (elementwise) multiply the attention weights to each vector and aggregates (them by summing) all vectors in a batch.

Comment: It worked. Could you give me some directions to what the `att_scores[..., None])`  means? Is it another approach to reshape?

Comment: `None` simply adds a new dimension to the tensor. It makes the `att_scores` of shape (2, 3, 1) so that it becomes compatible for [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with the output tensor of shape (2, 3, 5).

Comment: Great, thank you. It is like `att_scores.unsqueeze(-1)`.

Comment: You can also look up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241056/how-does-numpy-newaxis-work-and-when-to-use-it) answer for more explanation on numpy newaxis.

Comment: Yeah exactly like the unsqueeze operation!