# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead , euclidean distance

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, euclidean-distance

I got `(150, 4)` and `(4,)`
How to calculate the euclidean distance

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
center_distances = np.array(euclidean_distances(X, middle_point))
```

and I getting this error

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[5.84333333 3.05733333 3.758      1.19933333].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or 
array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to broadcast `middle_point` to the shape of `X`. You can do so by expanding one dimension on the first axis. You can either do:

- with [`np.expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html):

  ```
  >>> np.expand_dims(middle_point, 1)`)
  ```
- with slice tricks and `None` (equivalent to [`np.newaxis`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241056/how-does-numpy-newaxis-work-and-when-to-use-it)):

  ```
  >>> middle_point[None]
  ```

This allows to broadcast `middle_point` to an array of shape `(1, 4)`.

As a result you get an array containing the distances between each of the *150* points in `X` and the unique point in `middle_point`:

```
>>> euclidean_distances(X, middle_point[None])
# shape (150, 1)
```