# create new numpy array base on exist numpy array after many caculate step

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have a 2D array numpy s like this:

```
s = np.array([[ 5.,  4., np.nan,  1., np.nan],
       [np.nan,  4.,  4.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3., np.nan, np.nan,  5.,  5.],
       [np.nan,  3.,  4.,  4., np.nan]])

#now i want to create a new np array s1 base on s like this

s1= np.empty((len(s),len(s)))
for i  in range(len(s)):
    a = np.abs(s - s[i])
    a = np.nanmean(a, axis=1)
    w = 1 / (a + 0.001)
    s1[i] = w
s1
array([[1000.        ,    1.99600798,    0.33322226,    0.49975012],
       [   1.99600798, 1000.        ,    0.33322226,    0.999001  ],
       [   0.33322226,    0.33322226, 1000.        ,    0.999001  ],
       [   0.49975012,    0.999001  ,    0.999001  , 1000.        ]])

#without use for loop i write like this 

def f(x,y):
    a = np.abs(s[y]-s[x])
    a = np.nanmean(a)
    if np.isnan(a):
        return 0
    w = 1/(a+0.001) #not let 1/0
    return w

s1 = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(f),(len(s),len(s)),dtype='int')
s1
array([[1000.        ,    1.99600798,    0.33322226,    0.49975012],
       [   1.99600798, 1000.        ,    0.33322226,    0.999001  ],
       [   0.33322226,    0.33322226, 1000.        ,    0.999001  ],
       [   0.49975012,    0.999001  ,    0.999001  , 1000.        ]])
```

First i want to ask is my np.fromfunction right?
Second, are there another ways to rewrite this code with numpy without use for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
>>> 1/(
        1e-3 + np.nanmean(
            np.abs(s - s[:, None,:]),
            axis=2
        )
    )
array([[1.00000000e+03, 1.99600798e+00, 3.33222259e-01, 4.99750125e-01],
       [1.99600798e+00, 1.00000000e+03, 3.33222259e-01, 9.99000999e-01],
       [3.33222259e-01, 3.33222259e-01, 1.00000000e+03, 9.99000999e-01],
       [4.99750125e-01, 9.99000999e-01, 9.99000999e-01, 1.00000000e+03]])
```

Or in a fully numpy-idiomatic fashion

```
>>> np.reciprocal(1e-3 + np.nanmean(np.abs(s - s[:, np.newaxis, :]), axis=2))
array([[1.00000000e+03, 1.99600798e+00, 3.33222259e-01, 4.99750125e-01],
       [1.99600798e+00, 1.00000000e+03, 3.33222259e-01, 9.99000999e-01],
       [3.33222259e-01, 3.33222259e-01, 1.00000000e+03, 9.99000999e-01],
       [4.99750125e-01, 9.99000999e-01, 9.99000999e-01, 1.00000000e+03]])
```

<sub>*where, as of December 2021, [`np.newaxis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.newaxis) is `None`.*</sub>

Comment: thank Sir, you save me 1 more time. Where can i read document about create a new axis in numpy, i read np.newaxis in nympy doc but it so basic,... and i really dont know how it work

Comment: You are welcome @robocon20x Indeed, you are right: if you master newaxis-like stuffs, your NumPy-life is gonna be much easier. A first (good) link to grasp the thing is *[How does numpy.newaxis work and when to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41267079/4194079)*.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for a pure numpy solution:

```
repeat_s_by_array = np.repeat(s[np.newaxis,:,:], repeats=len(s), axis=0) 
repeat_s_by_rows = np.repeat(s, repeats=len(s), axis=0).reshape(len(s),len(s),-1)
abs_vals = np.abs(repeat_s_by_array - repeat_s_by_rows)
mean = np.nanmean(abs_vals, axis=-1)
s1 = 1 / (mean + 0.001)
```

Or you can do a one-liner:

```
s1 = 1 / (np.array([np.nanmean(np.abs(s - s[i]), axis=1) for i in range(len(s))]) + 0.001)
```

Comment: if i divide s rows to many part, call a is the number of row. should i change repeats from len(s) to a? your code seem work with small size of s

Comment: If your job is the same as in your original question, it must be `repeats=len(a)`. But because numpy solution deals with a much larger array, if `s` has many rows, then your original loop construction or the one-liner in my answer may begin to perform better.