# Random Search: Constructing set of unit directions

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, optimization

I am currently looking into an example implementation of [Random Search](https://github.com/jermwatt/machine_learning_refined/blob/gh-pages/notes/2_Zero_order_methods/2_5_Random.ipynb) from *Machine Learning Refined* and have trouble understanding the following code snippet where *w* is an input vector and *num_samples* is number of random directions to sample:

```
# construct set of random unit directions
directions = np.random.randn(num_samples,np.size(w))
norms = np.sqrt(np.sum(directions*directions,axis = 1))[:,np.newaxis]
directions = directions/norms
```

What I do understand is that we sample random vectors in the size of *w*, which we then need to normalize in order to get unit directions. So we calculate `|V| = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)` for all directions or `V/|V| = (x/|V|, y/|V|, z/|V|)` respectively.

Could someone explain to me in simple terms what happens in line 3, specifically why we sum over axis=1 and what the `[:,np.newaxis]` does? I have a vague grasp on what this is supposed to do, but some intuition would help a lot.

Comment: Sum over `axis=1` means calculate the sum for each sample (return a `num_samples x 1`  vector). If you don't specify `axis=1`, it will calculate the total sum (return a scalar). `[:,np.newaxis]` is used to add dimension.

Answer (score 0):

As wong.lok.yin pointed out in the comments, the line

```
norms = np.sqrt(np.sum(directions*directions,axis = 1))[:,np.newaxis]
```

sums over axis=1 (the column axis) and adds a new axis to the resulting vector by `[:,np.newaxis]`. There is a good explanation of how np.newaxis works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241056/how-does-numpy-newaxis-work-and-when-to-use-it).

Thanks @wong.lok.yin for the help.